# Django turn ChoiceField into a submit button

Tags: python, django, django-template-language

I have made a `ChoiceField` into a select and submit button and wondered if this is the correct approach.

forms.py

```
class PortfolioForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PortfolioForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        portfolios = [('pf 1', 'pf 1'), ('pf 2', 'pf 2'), ('pf 3', 'pf 3')]

        self.fields['portfolios'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                    widget=forms.Select(),
                    choices=portfolios,
                    required=False,
                    )
```

views.py

```
class PortfolioView(View):

    form_class = PortfolioForm
    template_name = 'portfolio.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            selected_portfolio = form.cleaned_data.get('portfolios')
            print(selected_portfolio) 
            form = self.form_class(initial={'portfolios': selected_portfolio})

        else:
            form = self.form_class(initial={'portfolio_name': ''})

        return render(self.request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

and most of the trickery in the template. I use elements of `form.portfolios` to make the buttons, but it seems I have to include `form.portfolios` in the template to make it all work. In order not to show I put this in a hidden  tag.

```
{% block content %}
  <form id="id_portfolio" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a style="visibility: hidden">{{ form.portfolios }}</a>
    {% for portfolio in form.portfolios %}
      <p>
      {% if portfolio.data.selected %}
        <button type="button">{{ portfolio.choice_label }}</button>

      {% else %}
        <button type="submit" value="{{ portfolio.data.value }}" 
          name="{{ portfolio.data.name }}">{{ portfolio.choice_label }}</button>

      {% endif %}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I haven't tried replicating this on my own machine, but what goes terribly wrong if you just use Django's built-in form rendering using [``{{ form }}``](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-template)?

Comment: Just rendering the built-in form `{{ form.portfolios }}` gives me a dropdown list. I want the buttons to be visible at all time.

Comment: Do you want there to be a button for each portfolio choice on the page? It may be better to override the `Select` widget and replace the `select.html` template with a template that renders buttons instead of a dropdown select

Comment: @mikeyl, yes correct I do not want the dropdown but still want to use the choicefied. Can you point me to how to replace the select.html with one that renders buttons.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the options to appear on the page, I would recommend using the `RadioSelect` widget instead. You will still need to click a separate button to submit however.

```
class PortfolioForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PortfolioForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        portfolios = [('pf 1', 'pf 1'), ('pf 2', 'pf 2'), ('pf 3', 'pf 3')]

        self.fields['portfolios'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                    widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
                    choices=portfolios,
                    required=False,
                    )
```

If you would like your own custom widget instead, you can inherit one of the existing widgets and apply your own template.

```
# widgets.py
class ButtonSelect(ChoiceWidget):
    template_name = 'widgets/button_select.html'
    option_template_name = 'widgets/button_select_option.html'


# templates/widgets/button_select.html
{% include "django/forms/widgets/multiple_input.html" %}

# templates/widgets/button_select_option.html
""""
Will need custom widget option code here.
Take a look at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/input_option.html
"""
```

Then you can use it in your `PortfolioForm`

```
from widgets import ButtonSelect

class PortfolioForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PortfolioForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        portfolios = [('pf 1', 'pf 1'), ('pf 2', 'pf 2'), ('pf 3', 'pf 3')]

        self.fields['portfolios'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                    widget=ButtonSelect(),
                    choices=portfolios,
                    required=False,
                    )
```